# Write a join subquery within a select query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this query that works in a separate worksheet.

```
SELECT
location_key AS carrier_company_name,
FROM INGEST.LOCATION_
JOIN INGEST.LOAD_ 
ON INGEST.LOAD_.dwh_masterclient_id = INGEST.LOCATION_.dwh_masterclient_id
```

Now, I want to use it within another query. So basically, I want to select the dwh_masterclient_id from the LOAD table and then I want to select `the location_key` AS `carrier_company_name` from the LOCATION table after joining on the basis of dwh_masterclient_ids that exist in both tables.
I am trying this

```
USE DATABASE PROD_DWH;
SELECT
cast(dwh_masterclient_id as smallint) AS dwh_masterclient_id,
(SELECT
location_key
FROM INGEST.LOCATION_
JOIN INGEST.LOAD_ 
ON INGEST.LOAD_.dwh_masterclient_id = INGEST.LOCATION_.dwh_masterclient_id),
1 as exception_codes
FROM INGEST.LOAD_
```

but it gives me an error

```
Single-row subquery returns more than one row.
```

Comment: `as varchar(255)`, but no `cast`?

Comment: Anyway, the subquery looks odd. Try a LEFT JOIN instead.

Comment: Ah I removed the cast but then it says ```Single-row subquery returns more than one row.```, which is weird bc I am only selecting one column name i.e location_key? @jarlh I am new to this, what would be the ideal syntax for a left join?

Comment: One column, but many rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow several location rows, skip the subquery and do a `LEFT JOIN` instead. Something like:

```
SELECT cast(dwh_masterclient_id as smallint) AS dwh_masterclient_id,
       location_key,
       1 as exception_codes
FROM INGEST.LOAD_
LEFT JOIN INGEST.LOCATION_
  ON INGEST.LOAD_.dwh_masterclient_id = INGEST.LOCATION_.dwh_masterclient_id
```